# Vue router 4 and vue 3 app showing component twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router4

I just installed vue-router 4 into a vue 3 application. When setting up my home route I keep getting the application displaying twice and even the navigation twice but cannot figure out why. I tried bringing in the `Navigation` component into `App.vue` and `Home.vue` but still shows twice. Is there something off that I am overlooking here?

router/index.js

```js
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import About from "@/components/About";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
    },
    {
        path: "/about",
        name: "About",
        component: About,
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

Navigation.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Navigation'
}
</script>
```

Home.vue

```html
<template>
    <Header/>
    <Navigation/>
    <div>
        <About/>
    </div>
</template>
```

App.vue

```html
<template>
  <Home/>
</template>

<script>
import Home from "@/components/Home";
export default {
  components: {Home}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Home` contains `Navigation` (which contains `<router-view>`, rendering the current route) *and* `About`. Since `About` is always rendered, you'd see two of them if the current route were `/about`.

```html
<template>
  <Header/>
  <Navigation/> <!-- contains router-view -->
  <div>
    <About/> <!-- ❌ always rendered in addition to current route -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Your current route configuration has no child routes, so there should only be one `<router-view>`, and it's usually in the root component (`App.vue`):

*App.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <Header />
  <Navigation />
  <router-view />
</template>
```

*Navigation.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  </div>
  <!--<router-view/> ❌ move to App.vue -->
</template>
```

*Home.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <!--<Header/> ​❌ move to App.vue -->
  <!--<Navigation/> ❌ move to App.vue -->
  <div>
    <About />
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-router-demo-fk5fky?file=src%2FApp.vue)